# Why doesn't .NET Core CORS Policy return Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Here is the code from the example:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "MyPolicy",
                policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                        "http://www.contoso.com",
                        "https://cors1.azurewebsites.net",
                        "https://cors3.azurewebsites.net",
                        "https://localhost:56055",
                        "https://localhost:5001")
                            .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET");
                });
});
```

[Here is a screenshot of the Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKo6t.png)

Comment: Hello did you try the solution? Was that helpful to resolve your issue? Feel free to share if you have any further concern on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I inspect the response headers, I do not see a
> `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header as I do with the live
> example URL.Why is this? Why is that header missing?

No, you cannot see the `response-header` unless you don't expose that explicitly. Usually, the browser doesn't expose all of the response headers to the app. You have to use `.WithExposedHeaders("x-custom-header");` to implement that. See the updated code below:

```cs
    var myCorsPolicy = "MyCorsPolicy";
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(myCorsPolicy,
            policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                           "http://www.contoso.com",
                           "https://cors1.azurewebsites.net",
                           "https://cors3.azurewebsites.net",
                           "https://localhost:56055",
                           "https://localhost:5001")
                      .WithExposedHeaders("kiron-test-custom-header")
                      .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET");
                      
            });
    });


    app.UseCors(myCorsPolicy);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

You can set any `header` you want to expose using `.WithExposedHeaders("any-custom-header")`. You can check here in the [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-exposed-response-headers)

Comment: My problem was that I had a closing slash in the origin, which of course makes it an invalid origin. wrong: `http://example.com/` correct: `http://example.com`