# React: CORS issue intermittently not able to get any data from web api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am having two applications React and WebApi asp.net core applications. I have enabled cors in startup.cs of webapi application. First time, when page loads I am able to get/post the data from api.

1. Cors issue occurs when user opens the website in multiple tabs, session timeout and when logout happens, or intermittently giving cors issues.
2. Error: Access to fetch at ‘/api/lastvisited' from origin 'https://localhost.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
3. POST https://localhost/api/v1/lastvisited net::ERR_FAILED 302 (anonymous)
4. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

```
webapi programs.cs
namespace WebAPI
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

```
webapi statup.cs
namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
      public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            WebHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
        }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {            AppHttpContext.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
            //Allow cors domain
            string[] CORSAllowedDomains = Configuration.GetSection("CORSAllowedDomains").Get<string[]>();
            app.UseCors(
               options => options.WithOrigins(
               CORSAllowedDomains).WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()          );
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            if (!WebHostEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Local"))
            {
                app.UseForwardedHeaders();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
        }
    }
}
```

```
export class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }

  onLogout() {
    const d = new Date();
    let lastVisitedDateTime = d.toLocaleString();
    lastVisitedDateTime = lastVisitedDateTime.replace(",", "");
    const data = {
      lastVisitedDateTime
    };
    const SERVICE_URL = "/lastvisiteddateandtime";
         fetch(SERVICE_URL, {
         method: "POST",
         headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
         credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
 window.sessionStorage.clear();
 window.location.href = "/";
  }
  render() {
    return (
                <Link         
                  onClick={this.onLogout.bind(this)}>
                  Logout</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Could you please share your `program.cs` or `web API CORS` configuration?

Comment: Please check if you configured the [`CORS settings accordingly`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73037479/why-doesnt-net-core-cors-policy-return-access-control-allow-origin-response-he/73049668#73049668) here

Comment: I updated the code with my webapi program and startup.cs file

Comment: on refreshing the page multiple times, then website starts displaying the data.

Comment: Did you try defining the cors policy as like this `policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com","http://www.contoso.com","https://cors1.azurewebsites.net")` if the issue still persist.

Comment: yes, i tried that too. issue is still there.

Comment: when cors is not working, i saw that in developer resources, urls having chunk.css.map was showing pending. when it changes to success and then refresh the page, cors issue is gone after that.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `app.UseCors()` middware after `app.UseRouting()`

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware) for more details

The order of middlewares :

[image]

Comment: i need to move app.UseCors(
               options => options.WithOrigins(
               CORSAllowedDomains).WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()          );
          after app.userouting(). ?

Comment: you could try with the settings in the document,if you still have  got the error,it may help if you could upload the minimal codes that could reproduce the error

Comment: you've called .AllowAnyMethod() so  .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST") is not necessary

Comment: i tried this. issue is still there. first time website works. if i open the website on multiple tabs, the cors issue is coming. its showing ....chunk.css.map urls pending. as soon as it changes to success and then i refresh, website is working fine

Comment: Please help. First time website displays the data. But if we open another tab and try to browse the website , website displays nothing. I need to wait for sometime and then refresh the page. its showing these issues: Cors issue occurs when user opens the website in multiple tabs, session timeout and when logout happens, or intermittently giving cors issues.

Error: Access to fetch at ‘/api/lastvisited' from origin 'https://localhost.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: what's the httpscheme of CORSAllowedDomains? http or https?

Comment: https.: First time cors is working fine. Issue1. session expired and then load the website again, no data coming, showing cors issue, if i refresh the data after some time, then cors is working fine. Issue2: Browse the website on multiple tabs, cors issue comes sometimes. Issue3, while working on the website, if i click the pages fast, then also it cause cors issue.